# If $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ are iid normal with mean 0 and variance $\theta$ unknown, find the Jeffry Prior for $\theta$

Tags: statistics

So I have the following,

$L(x|\theta)=-\frac{1}{2}ln(2\pi)-\frac{1}{2}ln(\sigma^{2})-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}x^2$

Then the first derivative is,

$-\frac{1}{2\sigma^{2}}+\frac{x^{2}}{(\sigma^{2})^{2}}$

Then the second derivative is,

$\frac{1}{(\sigma^{2})^{2}}-\frac{2x^{2}}{(\sigma^{2})^{4}}$

So to find the Jeffry Prior you find the negative expected value of the log likelihoods second derivative which is,

$-E(\frac{1}{(\sigma^{2})^{2}}-\frac{2x^{2}}{(\sigma^{2})^{4}})$

But since $\mu$=0 then $E(x)=\mu=0$ so I got,

$-E(\frac{1}{(\sigma^{2})^{2}}) = -\frac{1}{(\sigma^{2})^{2}}$

But the Jeffry Prior is the square root of this function yet its negative, can anyone tell me if I'm doing anything wrong?

Comment: Hint: to prevent confusions in the calculation of derivative, denote the variance $\sigma^2$ (your parameter) by a single letter, ($s$ or $\theta$).

Comment: Not only are you making mistakes in the derivate (in the first, for example, the second term should not lose the 2 denominator) but in the end you seem to assume that if $E(X)=0$ then $E(X^2)=0$ which is false.